# How does indirect/reported speech work when there are multiple verbs, one imperfect?

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales

I understand (in theory) the idea of how reported speech in Spanish works. The verb basically rolls back a degree unless it's imperfect, conditional, pluperfect, or conditional perfect. But what happens when there are multiple verbs, with one in the imperfect or any of the others that don't change? Does something like:

> Adam dijo: "Tú corrías cuando te vi".

become

> Adam dijo que yo corría cuando me había visto.

English could use the pluperfect there but it often just...doesn't colloquially, which might be what's throwing me off. Is it ever correct to say:

> Adam dijo que yo corría cuando me vio.

Answer (score 1):

Este tema ya se ha discutido dos veces. Sin embargo, considero que merece que se vuelva a tratar una vez más. Para saber más, lean [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/369/does-indirect-speech-in-spanish-require-changes-in-tense-mood-etc) y [esta otra](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31252/indirect-speech-breaking-the-rules-of-it).

> The verb basically rolls back a degree...

Te voy a contar un secreto: esas reglas de conversión de tiempos verbales de pretérito no existen. Nunca han existido, son solamente un ‘invento’, el cual permite simplificar la teoría en los cursos que se les dan a los extranjeros. No me malinterpreten. No estoy diciendo que sean inútiles. Lo que quiero decir es que siempre que se comienza aprendiendo un idioma nos van a ofrecer una versión recortada que se basa en las generalidades.

Con toda la furia, lo que un nativo sabe es algo como esto:

> El uso del estilo indirecto requiere de algunos cambios en la oración para poder establecer las correctas relaciones de concordancia entre los tiempos verbales, los pronombres u otros elementos deícticos que puedan aparecer. [[Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/estilo-directo-e-indirecto/)]

Pero no necesita saber ninguna ‘regla de conversión’ porque ya sabe intuitivamente como hacerlo, y porque además sabe que el tiempo apropiado va a depender de lo que quiera expresar en cada situación y éste no queda unívocamente determinado con el tiempo del verbo en la cita directa. Quisiera que me comenten si en el inglés es igual, yo no creo que les enseñen reglas como éstas en las escuelas.

Por lo tanto, es cierto que las dos estructuras que presentás son correctas. La primera es ligeramente más formal debido a una anfibología que hay en la segunda frase, a saber:

> Adam dijo [que yo corría cuando me vio]. (Lo dijo)
> Adam dijo [que yo corría] cuando me vio. (Lo dijo cuando me vio)

Que podría resultar en una ambigüedad si el contexto no permite decidirse por una de las dos opciones. Mientras que la primera no me lleva a considerar ambas opciones puesto que no sé si la construcción ‘lo *dijo* cuando me *había visto*(?)’ (pretérito perfecto + ‘cuando’ + ‘había’) es aceptable, pero como mínimo es muy dudosa. Pero en ninguna de tus dos oraciones veo un problema grave de concordancia.

Lo raro es el tiempo que elegiste, porque el pretérito imperfecto se prefiere en general para acciones prolongadas en el pasado. Es decir, lo que planteás sonaría bien—aunque sin librarte de la anfibología—si tu ejemplo fuera:

> Adam dijo que yo **estaba** en el tercer año de la facultad cuando se **recibió**.

Pero como supongo que la acción de correr sucedió una vez y no quisiste referirte a ella como un hábito prolongado del pasado, lo que se prefiere es—y notar que insisto con lo de ‘se prefiere’ porque también es posible usar ‘corría’:

> Amam dijo: ‘Estabas corriendo cuando te vi/había visto’.
> Adam dijo que yo **estaba corriendo** cuando me **había visto**.
> Adam dijo que yo **estaba corriendo** cuando me **vio**.

**Conclusión**: No hay algo así como ‘reglas de conversión de verbos’ para pasar del estilo directo al indirecto. Los tiempos verbales apropiados deben determinarse según cada circunstancia particular para que la frase no pierda sentido ni concordancia. Del mismo modo, cuando la frase en estilo directo es demasiado larga a veces conviene directamente acortarla o reformularla con las propias palabras para ahorrarse dolores de cabeza con las ‘conversiones’.